# Technical engineering user stories (tasks) in UX?

Tags: user-research

The engineers of my team are building the tasks of the app already in the first stage. Is it correct? I think that before that, we should create the user stories. Even more, we should do some research first. Am I in the right way?

Comment: Based on what are the engineers building at the moment, if there are no user stories?

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly normal for an engineering team to start work on some of the less visible parts of a product once basic requirements are in. That might be spinning up environments, getting databases set up, getting API access, etc.

They might also being to work on finding possible solutions to some of the larger scale problems if they can see them coming.

If, for instance, they can see that your app will need to talk to an API and store and retrieve information from a database then they might be writing stories that say things like "as a user I want to be able to see 'x' from the API" or "as a user I want to be able to retrieve 'y' from database 'z'".

They might also be writing stories for other developers and systems admins

Comment: but perhaps some of that less visible parts can be useless if you don´t research in the ux phase previously, isn´t it?

Comment: No - the requirements that drive that work will be coming from the business analysis or service design (if you have them) or a basic assessment of the technical requirements from the early product definition given by the end client

Comment: It depends on what you define as "basic requirements". The engineers can't possibly know everything in advance, so they will either not build the right application, or they will build extra's (to make sure they aren't missing anything) that later turn out were not needed, so they wasted resources.

Comment: Having worked with development teams from 1 to 25+ in size I can tell you that, as soon as you have enough product definition to begin UX there is also enough to begin the groundwork for development and it is perfectly normal for this to happen. It depends on what the dev team see as actionable in the brief from the Business Analysts or Service Designers. They will not be working on the user interface. They will be designing and building the underlying system architecture required to enable the high level functionality.

Comment: In my view the correct place to start is with market research: will the public want what you are proposing to build ?

Comment: @PhillipW ...and that informs the business analysis or service design which, in turn, informs both the basic engineering requirements and the basic UX requirements together.

Comment: Yes.  And no matter how good YOU think your product is, you should find out whether potential customers actually want it - before you spend a lot of time and money building it.

Comment: That's exactly the way we have been building products for years - rushing to implement solutions before understanding the problem and actual users' needs. It seems so clear to just query database X, use framework Y and throw out the results. Finally we lose ourselves in unexpected bugs and technical details, "solve" them with cryptic UI messages instead of investing our times into true understanding and design from the beginning. That's how products still fail.